# How to fix getting Arabic characters display in TListView?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-11-alexandria

The address book sample displays Arabic characters messed up, like that `س ا ش ص`. I tried to change the font of the text item to "Arial" or "Courier New", but the result is the same. Is there a way to display non-English characters correctly in `TListView`?

Loading contacts code:

```
procedure TForm1.FillContactList(Source: TAddressBookSource);
var
  I: Integer;
  Contacts: TAddressBookContacts;
begin
  Contacts := TAddressBookContacts.Create;
  try
    AddressBook1.AllContacts(Source, Contacts);
    ListViewContacts.BeginUpdate;
    try
      ListViewContacts.Items.Clear;
      for I := 0 to Contacts.Count - 1 do
        AddListViewItem(Contacts.Items[I]);
    finally
      ListViewContacts.EndUpdate;
    end;
  finally
    Contacts.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.AddListViewItem(Contact: TAddressBookContact);
var
  ListViewItem: TListViewItem;
begin
  ListViewItem := ListViewContacts.Items.Add;
  ListViewItem.Text := Contact.DisplayName;
  ListViewItem.Tag := Contact.ID;
end;
```

Comment: It's not a Font problem, try to use SKIA4Delphi

Comment: Does fmx support rtl languages

Comment: @DavidHeffernan it does not ?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this however using Skia4Delphi might be worth a try: https://skia4delphi.org/

Comment: @zac it never used to

Comment: This is known issue: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-27872 Using Skia4Delphi should solve the problem. While this particular issue is due to lack of support for drawing fonts with ligatures, FMX in general does not have support for RTL.

Answer (score 0):

Skia indeed solved the problem. More Details:

https://github.com/skia4delphi/skia4delphi#right-to-left

**Right-to-Left**

Using Skia's Canvas, your application will now support Right-To-Left text rendering. But for that you will need to make 3 changes to your project:

```
Open the source of your Delphi Application Project (.dpr), include the line Application.BiDiMode := TBiDiMode.bdRightToLeft;, like below:

program Project1;

uses
  System.StartUpCopy,
  FMX.Forms,
  System.Classes,
  Skia.FMX,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.BiDiMode := TBiDiMode.bdRightToLeft;
  GlobalUseSkia := True;
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.

Set the property BiDiMode of your forms to bdRightToLeft;
Keyboard input controls like TEdit and TMemo, need to be fixed by Embarcadero, meanwhile, as a workaround, set the ControlType property of these controls to Platform.
```